# NEG in Assembly

Tags: assembly

```
neg 3BH
```

As I understand, I should get `C5`, but from my own calculations I got `C4` (I switch each 1 to 0 and each 0 to 1). What's the problem?

Comment: 0xFF - 0x3B = 0xC4 This is performing a bitwise invert. C4 is the correct answer. Why do you think you should get C5?

Comment: He expects C5 because he's looking for the algebraic negative, not the logical negation.

Comment: OP -- Why do you refuse to tell us what the CPU is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*neg* computes the two's complement negative value, not the bitwise negative. You'll want a *not* instruction, or manually add one to the answer to get your desired result.

Comment: Seems that your neg is a not after all? Are you sure you haven't swithced the values?

Comment: I don't know what it *should* do on your platform, neg usually is two's complement.

Comment: So 'C5' is the result for neg two's complement?

Comment: Fun fact: x86's `neg` sets flags the same as `sub` from `0`.  (Not any other way of computing the 2's complement negation).

Answer (score 1):

As you tell the story, it seems that the `neg` instruction (on whatever CPU you're using) effectively performs an xor of 3BH with FFH to give C4H. To that C4H result, which is the ones complement of 3BH, add 1 to get the twos complement. That will yield the correct C5H value you want. For an overview of ones and twos complement, have a look at this pretty-good  [**Wikipedia article**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

Comment: What you describe (XORing with 0FFh) is what `NOT` does, not `NEG`. At least, that's the case for x86.

Comment: I think the OP is saying that by hand on paper they got 0xC4, when the correct result for `neg` on whatever ISA they're talking about is `0xC5`.  On 2's complement hardware, the `neg` mnemonic (if one exists) is pretty much always 2's complement negation, not one's complement.

Answer (score 0):

neg is the same as subtracting 0-the number,do it and you will get the negation of the number :0-3BH:

0-00111011:

00000000

11000100              +
       1           +

---

11000101=C5

Answer (score 0):

`NEG 3Bh` is equivalent to finding `2's complement`.
 1st, find `1's complement`, a faster approach is to subtract from 15 (F in hex).

```
      15 - 3 = 12 ->C (12 = C in hex)
      15 - 0Bh = 4h OR 15 - 11 = 4h
      then, add 1 to the result.
      C4 + 1 = C5h.
```

This how you will get `C5h` as the result of `NEG 3Bh`.

Comment: `15 - B` is really confusing notation.  If you're mixing decimal and hex in the same expression, write it as `15 - 0xB` or avoid mixing and write `F - B`.